# Many to Many association returns a different id, how can I associate correctly?

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, associations

So I have User and Module tables user has an array of module_id in the module property.
I created a many-to-many association

```
User.belongsToMany(Module, { through: 'user_module', foreignKey: 'user_id' });
Module.belongsToMany(User, { through: 'user_module', foreignKey: 'module_id' });
```

When I add a new user I notice that the module_id is different even if I had added the same module_id.
This is the command I used:

```
const user = await User.create({ name: 'John Doe', modules: [module.module_id], module: [module.module_id] }, {
            include: [{ model: Module }], 
        });
```

I noticed that with this command a new module is created, but if I delete modules: [module.module_id], it does return only null with user_module.

How should I write this in order to add the user with the right module_id and retrieve also the module when I try to find?